# Writing a *finite* power series as a rational expression

Tags: power-series, rational-functions

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{14}(-3)^kx^{2k}
$$
I know that to get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-3)^kx^{2k} = \frac3{3+x^2}
$$

Comment: Hint:  Let $f(x)$ be your expression.  What is the product $(-3)x^2f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$\frac1{1-x}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$,
we have
$x^m\frac1{1-x}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^mx^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{m+n}
=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} x^{n}
$.

Subtracting,
$\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^{n}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}-\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} x^{n}
=\frac1{1-x}-\frac{x^m}{1-x}
=\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}
$.

A nice thing about this result
is that it is true for
any $x \ne 1$,
even though the original sum
is valid only for
$-1 \le x < 1$.

Therefore
$\sum_{k=0}^{14}(-3)^kx^{2k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{14}(-3x^2)^{k}
=\frac{1-(-3x^2)^{15}}{1-(-3x^2)}
$
by replacing $m$ with $15$
and
$x$ with
$-3x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** can you do
$$ \sum_{k=15}^{\infty} (-3)^kx^{2k}? $$

> \begin{align} =((-3)x^2)^{15} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-3)^m x^{2m} \end{align}